# How can I make my textarea fit my responsive layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I make this textarea (the one with `class="proxi-output"` responsive?
When I try to resize the page it overlaps div (`class="resi-gen"`) and it breaks the whole web.

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body,
html{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(../img/agreya-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #0E0E0E;
}

.side-panel{
    background-color: #050707;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}

.logo{
    margin: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 35px 20%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.sub-pages{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 150px auto;
}

.sub-pages a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 45px 0px;
}

.sub-pages a:hover{
    color: #E1E777;
}

#current{
    color: #E1E777;
}

.heading{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper{
    float: right;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}

.resi-gen{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #050707;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 45%;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /* width: 1100px;
    height: 400px; */
    margin-left: 290px;
}
.resi-gen h2{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 20px; 
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}


#proxi-output{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 85%;
    width: 70%; 
    resize: none;
    background-color: #818181;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid transparent;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/residental.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29441bec37.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Agreya - Register</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="side-panel">
            <h1 class="logo">AGREYA</h1>

            <div class="sub-pages">
                <a id="current" href="residental.html">Residental</a>
                <a href="datacenter.html">Datacenter</a>
                <a href="purchase.html">Purchase</a>
                <a href="settings.html">Settings</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <h1 class="heading">Residental proxies</h1>

        <div class="resi-gen">
            <h2>Generate Proxies</h2>

            <textarea id="proxi-output" name="output"></textarea>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don't ask two questions at a time. Ask the second one in a separate post.